# Can I Lock Console.Out to prevent garbled text-output?

Tags: c#, .net

Anyone who did multithreaded code has surely had issues where writing console output gets messed up. It's a classic race example.
As I understand it (not well) a simple solution is to use `lock` but then you need to have some global object or method all threads can access.

So I wonder can you just use an existing object e.g.:

```
lock(Console.Out){
 Console.Write("This is definitely OK");
}
```

Note: I *am* aware that if this is just diagnostic text, we also risk the classic problem where outputting debug text changes the flow of operations and can mask multithreading code bugs "it works in debug". I am talking about a program that actually writes to Console as part of its operation.

Comment: You'd encounter the same problem if you tried to log to a file with a simple `AppendAllText`. All logging libraries solve this by serializing the messages, and many of them do so asynchronously. You shouldn't be trying to create your own logging like this.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to create a command-line tool, errors should go to a different stream, Console.Error. An even better idea would be a Powershell command, which gives you object streams instead of text streams, separate Info, Warning, Debug and even Progress streams

Comment: Locking on something that is publicly available can cause troubles when other code also locks on that particular object, and then calls into your code, which could then cause a deadlock that is probably really hard to find.

Comment: Technically it's possible but you will lose a lot of performance as all your tasks would have to wait for the lock to free up, slowing everything down.

Comment: @Longoon12000 surely if you're writing to a console window it's already slow?

Comment: A common way to solve this is to post messages to a queue and have a single worker write the text to the destination. You could do this with a simple `ActionBlock<string>(line=>File.AppendAllText(myLogPath,line));`

Comment: Yes but that's the point, if you queue up your messages and have them written to console in a task separate to what your program is doing then you won't lose any time waiting for Console.WriteLine.

Comment: @Mr.Boy writing to any log, console or not, doesn't have to be slow

Comment: @bassfader that's an interesting point although a `lock` block that calls `Console.Write` and then calls into your code is badly written - locks should be as minimal as possible

Comment: @Mr.Boy what are you trying to do? Why not use eg Serilog or log4Net? Or even .NET's own TraceListener? This is a solved problem, with built-in support.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sure but for most console applications driven by user operation, performance is not an issue. If you want to be able to read the text and respond, YOU are the limiting factor :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's a simple test app. Bringing in logging frameworks is total overkill but I need to avoid output getting screwed up so you can see what is happening

Comment: @Mr.Boy again, what are you trying to do? And if you want to mix input and responses, you no longer have "just" a console application. At the very least you should ensure the logs appear in a *different* location. You can't just log to `Out` any more.

Comment: @Mr.Boy it's not a "simple" test app any more, it needs a real UI. You can write to different locations in the screen by changing the cursor position (that's what utilities do). In the new Windows Terminal you can use ASCII escape sequences for this. Miguel de Icaza even wrote [gui.cs](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs) to allow creating console UIs

Comment: Another option to consider is side-stepping the problem altogether by creating a new window (with, say, a `ListBox` or suchlike) or `Process.Create`-ing a new process with its own console window and redirected input for the sole purpose of displaying whatever you want your debugging code to display. The former invites specific dependencies on windowing code, the latter invites problems with inter-process communication, but it's an option. An extremely low-cost, unintrusive option is using `DebugView` and P/Invoking to `OutputDebugString`, though I'd prefer a decent logging framework myself.